# Website using Subsonic not working live

Tags: c#, subsonic

This is a .net website that uses Subsonic 2.2, I can run it locally and it runs ok. Once put it live I get compilation errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'XXXX' does not exist in the namespace 'YYYY' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

YYYY is the dynamically generated namespace that Subsonic creates, this is created on the fly and is not a referenced DLL.

This is also a website, not a web application so there's no compiled DLLs to upload. Subsonic is using the .abp file method of generating the namepsace, so my suspicion is that it's not connecting to the DB, but the connection string is fine and works so I'm unsure.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Are all the subsonic dll's in the bin directory?

Comment: There's only one Subsonic DLL and it's in the bin directory. I'll update the question as I forgot to mention this is Subsonic 2.2